# Parameters merging with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, mod-rewrite

I'm currently using the following line to convert `/pages/group/index.php?id=1&slug=example-name` into `group/1-example-name` which works perfectly and I can retrieve the ID and slug using `$_GET` but when I try to add an additional parameter for the page number, I cannot retrieve the page number and it becomes part of the slug.

Two parameters

```
RewriteRule ^group/([^-]*)-([^.]*)$ /pages/group/index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L]
```

Additional third parameter

```
RewriteRule ^group/([^-]*)-([^.]*)/([0-9]+)$ /pages/group/index.php?id=$1&slug=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

So if the ID parameter is 1, the slug parameter is hello-example and the page parameter is 10 - the ID will return perfectly but the slug will return as hello-example/10 and the page number will return as empty.

Any help would be much appreciated :)!

Comment: Your first rule will match both URLs, and stop the new rule being reached. Put the most specific rule first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments, the string "some-title/pagenumber" is matched by the first rewriterule. It will therefore never be matched by the second rewriterule. In this case you just want the rules to be matched in the opposite order, so just switch the order of the rules:

```
RewriteRule ^group/([^-]*)-([^.]*)/([0-9]+)$ /pages/group/index.php?id=$1&slug=$2&page=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^group/([^-]*)-([^.]*)$ /pages/group/index.php?id=$1&slug=$2 [L]
```